# How can I return only a specific part of a column?

Tags: mysql

So I have a column that returns a string that looks like this:

```
part1 > part2 > part3
```

I want to be able to return only part 2 when I select that row, but I can't quite figure out how to do it. The closest I've gotten is through this statement:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(column_name, INSTR(column_name, ">") +2)

FROM
table;
```

Which returns `part2 > part3`.

I looked into using RegEx, but I'm really not steady on that and I can't seem to wrap my head around how I would build that statement...
If anyone could give me some pointers, that would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Trim()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function alongwith [Substring_Index()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SELECT TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_name, " > ", 2), " > ", -1)) 
FROM table
```

**Details:**

- From [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) of `Substring_Index` function:

> Returns the substring from string str before count occurrences of the
>   delimiter delim. If count is positive, everything to the left of the
>   final delimiter (counting from the left) is returned. If count is
>   negative, everything to the right of the final delimiter (counting
>   from the right) is returned. SUBSTRING_INDEX() performs a
>   case-sensitive match when searching for delim.

- SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_name, " > ", 2) returns "**part1 > part2**"
- Further SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, " > ", -1) returns "**part2**"
- **Note the usage of leading and trailing spaces in the delimiter string `" > "`**
- TRIM clears all leading and trailing spaces (if any left).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column_name, ">" ,2), ">", -1)
```

mysql has a very useful SUBSTRING_INDEX function which gets the string only up to a particular substring or character. it also allows you to go backwards from the end of the string using a negative number. 
also, note that if you want to TRIM the spaces around the ">" (as someone else suggests) you can use " > " instead of just ">"

Comment: This answer might help the topicstarter but is off very low quality.. This answer does not contain an explainment of anny kind.

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary since the question was already on the right track, but i added some now